# Unresolved import `core::task::Wake`

Tags: heroku, rust, rust-cargo

I have a web server written in rust that I wanted to deploy on Heroku. The server compiles and runs well locally on my machine (see photos below), however, it cannot compile on rust and I get a compilation error.

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `core::task::Wake`

   --> /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/standback-0.2.16/src/lib.rs:520:13

    |

520 |     pub use core::task::Wake;

    |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^----

    |             |           |

    |             |           help: a similar name exists in the module (notice the capitalization): `wake`

    |             no `Wake` in `task`

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Working perfectly on my machine:
[image: Working perfectly on my machine]

Not compiling in Heroku
[image: Not compiling in Heroku]

(source code can be found [here](https://www.github.com/AkshatAdsule/keeper-api))

Comment: I ran into this error on one of my projects as well. Running `cargo update` fixed it.

Comment: I notice that your repository has Cargo.lock checked in.  You could try removing that from the repository to see if can build on the server.  You could also try deleting the .lock file locally, running cargo clean, and then building to see if you can reproduce the error locally

Comment: Thanks, IbraheemAhmed, and transistor. The issue was with an outdated version of the standback crate. Running cargo update, and removing the Cargo.lock file solved my issue! Thanks again!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an issue in the [`standback`](https://github.com/jhpratt/standback/issues/11) crate that was fixed a couple days ago in a new release. You can get the fix by updating the dependency in your `Cargo.lock` file with `cargo update` or `cargo update -p standback`.